# submitting a form after jquery validate - need to pass clicked button to post data

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have jquery validate 1.19.1 working correctly on a form.
The form has multiple buttons. My goal is to have which button was clicked pass to the post data so I can handle it on the forms postback.  Just using a submit button this works, I can handle in my php for example when the insert button is clicked:

```
    if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
        print_r($_POST); 
        // do insert
    }
```

...but with JQuery this doesn't work because it loses the insert button.
I was thinking maybe I can append the button to the form before submitting but haven't been successful, please advise?  My jquery code is below, thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#myForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {               
            // append button here?
        }
    });
    $('insert').click(function () {
        $('[name="manufacturerSelect"], [name="chassisNameInsert"]').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true
            });
        });  
        $('#myForm').submit();  // validate and submit
    });
    $('update').click(function () {
        $('[name="manufacturerSelect"], [name="chassisNameInsert"]').each(function () {                
            $(this).rules('remove');
        }); 
        $('#myForm').submit();  // validate and submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has a more elegant solution I think nevermind.  I got it to work like this:

```
    $('#insertButton').click(function () {
        $('[name="manufacturerSelect"], [name="chassisNameInsert"]').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true
            });
        });
        if ($('#myForm').valid()){
            var input = $('<input>')
               .attr('type', 'hidden')
               .attr('name', 'insert').val('true');
            $('#myForm').append($(input));   
            $('#myForm').submit();
        };            
    });
```